# Paypal SDK is not capturing money

Tags: javascript, paypal, nodes

Here is my NODEJS app request. I'm redirecting customer to `approve_url` where he writes his details. When PayPal accepts customer details, it redirects account back to `return_url`.

The question is, after successful redirect the customer is not getting charged and I don't see any activity in my PayPal. What am I doing wrong?

```
let pay_req = {
  'intent': 'CAPTURE',
  "application_context": {
    'return_url': `https://api.domain.com/orders/success`,
    'cancel_url': `https://api.domain.com/orders/cancel`,
    "brand_name": "Domain",
    "locale": "en-US",
    landing_page: "BILLING",
    "user_action": "PAY_NOW"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "name": entity.item.name,
      "description": entity.item.description,
      "unit_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": entity.item.price
      },

      "quantity": request_body.qty,
      "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
    }
  ],
  shipping_type: "shipping",
  purchase_units: [{
    "amount": {
      "currency_code": "USD",
      'value': total,
      "breakdown": {
        "item_total": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": subtotal
        },
        "shipping": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": shipping
        }
      }
    }
  }]
};
request.requestBody(pay_req);
let payPalClient = client();
let order;
try {
  order = await payPalClient.execute(request);
} catch (err) {

  // 4. Handle any errors from the call
  console.error(err);
  return err;
}
await strapi.services.order.update(
  {
    id: entity.id
  },
  {
    paypal_token: order.result.id
  }
);
var links = {};
order.result.links.forEach(function (linkObj) {
  links[linkObj.rel] = {
    'href': linkObj.href,
    'method': linkObj.method
  };
})
return links["approve"].href;
```

Comment: Hmm that is interesting, I wonder if the right client ID is being passed.

Comment: @IronMan everything is right, I can see activity log on PayPal Developer dashboard. But am I doing right by only executing this function and redirecting person to the approve url? should I do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The capture is *not* automatic.  You are expected to display an order review page, and send a capture request when the user confirms an order. If you wish to skip the order review step and capture immediately, you can do so -- but in that case you are expected to send a payment setup parameter that changes the blue "Continue" button within PayPal to say "Pay Now" instead (this is a cosmetic change only, but it informs the user of what will happen) -- and though you make that cosmetic change, you still have to send the capture request immediately when the user returns to the return_url.

---

For best results: forget all that, and forget using redirects. Don't use any redirects. At all. Instead, switch to this front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It's a much better payment experience, more in keeping with modern web design practice, which keeps your website loaded in the background and opens an "in context" approval window.

(You can see a working UI demo by clicking through the [serverless HTML/JS-only](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) version)